# Jquery run another function after 1st function completed

Tags: jquery, social-media

I'm not sure the best way to go about this so open to suggestions!

I am using this code to save canvas to png, which works great:

```
function save_image() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('container'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            var imgdata = imagedata.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

            $.ajax({
                url: 'save.php',
                data: {
                       imgdata:imgdata
                       },
                type: 'post',
                success: function (response) {  
                   $('#imgid img').attr('src', response);

                }
            });

        }
        });
    }
```

I want the user to be able to share their image to Facebook and pinterest.

The share to social media code works when I put the code in the success function above, but I thought I would be repeating code so I am going down the following route:

```
$(".pin").click(function(e) {
    saveimage();
    var image = $('#imgid img').attr('src');

    window.open('http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?'+ 'url='+encodeURIComponent("url here")+ '&media='+encodeURIComponent(image)+ '&description='+encodeURIComponent("title heree"));

});
```

However the image doesn't save quick enough and the window opens instantly, so say if I click to save on Pinterest again, the image appears.

How can I save to social media after the save function has completed?

I am also running the save_image() function for other functions in the app, so I was trying not to repeat code.

Would it be best to firstly find out when the image has been saved and then share to social media, or put a delay for the window to open? Also want to make sure the window doesn't get blocked by adblock or pop up blockers!

Can anyone help guide please?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need a call back function

```
function save_image(callBackFun) {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('container'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            var imgdata = imagedata.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

            $.ajax({
                url: 'save.php',
                data: {
                       imgdata:imgdata
                       },
                type: 'post',
                success: function (response) {  
                   $('#imgid img').attr('src', response);
                   callBackFun();

                }
            });

        }
        });
    }
```

---

```
$(".pin").click(function(e) {

    function callBackFun(){
        var image = $('#image_id img').attr('src');
        window.open('http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?'+ 'url='+encodeURIComponent("url here")+ '&media='+encodeURIComponent(image)+ '&description='+encodeURIComponent("title heree"));
    }

    saveimage(callBackFun);

});
```

*callBackFun* call after your ajax request was finished.

Comment: would you know a work around for pop up blockers? The window is being blocked in Chrome? it wasn't being blocked before?

Comment: what do you mean exactly ?